# Set boost::posix_time::duration to pos_infinite?

Tags: c++, boost

How does one set [`boost::posix_time::duration`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html) to positive infinite? The class contains an `is_pos_infinite` function, which retrieves `duration::tick_type::pos_infinite` for comparison, but I cannot work out how to retrieve this value and use it to set the duration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Constructor takes some "special values": not_a_date_time, pos_infin, or neg_infin.

```
time_duration td(pos_infin);
```

Documentation for boost can be a pain to read...

Comment: Seems not: `error: ‘pos_infinite’ is not a member of ‘boost::posix_time’`

Comment: pos_infin, not pos_infinite. They are brought into boost::posix_time namespace in "boost\date_time\posix_time\ptime.hpp"